# JavaScript / JQuery Invalid EWS SOAP XML Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, soap, exchangewebservices

I'm currently attempting to make a local extension to load data from an Outlook exchange web server that my company uses. The server is running an older version (pre-2013 when JSON support was added).

I've been able to pull the SOAP XML response with both JavaScript and JQuery, using XMLHttpRequest and $.Ajax, but both return invalid XML containing what seems to be separated XML. I've attempted to use Regular Expression to remove the line breaks and segments breaking the XML but it seems to fail to reply every time, producing no changes.

Here you can see how I make the request.

```
var xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>\
<soap:Envelope \
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" \
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">\
  <soap:Body>\
    <FindItem \
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" \
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" \
      Traversal="Shallow">\
      <ItemShape>\
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>\
      </ItemShape>\
      <ParentFolderIds>\
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />\
      </ParentFolderIds>\
    </FindItem>\
  </soap:Body>\
</soap:Envelope>'

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://{URL}/ews/exchange.asmx",
    data: xmlData,
    dataType: "xml",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    success: function (pData) {
        var s = pData.responseText.replace(/(\n[0-9]+\n)/g, ''); // This would replace the numbers seperating
        s = s.replace(/([0-9]+\n)/g, ''); // This replaces the first separator.
        // Neither of the two replace()'s above work or apply.
        console.log(s);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Here is the response XML, As you can see, the first line starts with **8000**, and that re-occurs evenly throughout the response (which is fairly large). I'll post a snippet of the end of the response after the below snippet.

**Edit:**  The `Error: Invalid XML: 8000` only appears when working with JQuery, when using an XMLHttpRequest object, it would just have `8000`, which is what the regular expression was built around.

```
Error: Invalid XML: 8000
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="468" MinorBuildNumber="0"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:RootFolder TotalItemsInView="625" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
            <t:Items>
              <t:Message>
                <t:ItemId Id="{Removed for StackOverflow}" ChangeKey="{Removed for StackOverflow}"/>
                <t:Subject>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:Subject>
                <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
                <t:Size>6348007</t:Size>
                <t:DateTimeSent>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:DateTimeSent>
                <t:DateTimeCreated>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:DateTimeCreated>
                <t:HasAttachments>true</t:HasAttachments>
                <t:From>
                  <t:Mailbox>
                    <t:Name>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:Name>
                  </t:Mailbox>
                </t:From>
                <t:IsRead>true</t:IsRead>
              </t:Message>
              <t:Message>
                <t:ItemId Id="{Removed for StackOverflow}" ChangeKey="{Removed for StackOverflow}"/>
                <t:Subject>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:Subject>
                <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
                <t:Size>2978</t:Size>
                <t:DateTimeSent>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:DateTimeSent>
                <t:DateTimeCreated>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:DateTimeCreated>
                <t:HasAttachments>false</t:HasAttachments>
                <t:From>
                  <t:Mailbox>
                    <t:Name>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:Name>
                  </t:Mailbox>
                </t:From>
                <t:IsRead>true</t:IsRead>
              </t:Message>
              <t:Message>
                <t:ItemId Id="{Removed for StackOverflow}" ChangeKey="{Removed for StackOverflow}"/>
                <t:Subject>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:Subject>
                <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
                <t:Size>4508</t:Size>
                <t:DateTimeSent>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:DateTimeSent>
                <t:DateTimeCreated>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:DateTimeCreated>
                <t:HasAttachments>false</t:HasAttachments>
                <t:From>
                  <t:Mailbox>
                    <t:Name>{Removed for StackOverflow}</t:Name>
                  </t:Mailbox>
                </t:From>
                <t:IsRead>true</t:IsRead>
              </t:Message>
            </t:Items>
          </m:RootFolder>
        </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:FindItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Now the end of the response I get the following:

```
</t:Message></t:Items></m:RootFolder></m:FindItemResponseMessage></m:ResponseMessages></m:FindItemResponse>
16
</s:Body></s:Envelope>
0
```

I'm new to EWS and the SOAP api, but it seems like the breaks in numbers are generated server-side, and are showing the size of data being sent to the client (me). I'm completely lost on this.

Answer (score 0):

After some more time doing thorough research, I found out that the issue happens when the Exchange server is using a load-balancer that is not up to date. You can work around this issue via bypassing the F5, but as I don't have rights to the server there wasn't much I could do. After trial and error I eventually produced a work-around, via JQuery's Ajax converters function. Below is the code that I was able to use properly convert the returned invalid xml into valid xml.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
    "text xml": function(xmlString) {
      console.log(typeof xmlString);
      var s = xmlString.replace(/(\n[0-9]+\n)/g, '');
      s = s.replace(/([0-9]+\r?\n|\r)/g, '');
      s = s.replace(/[0-9]+\r?\n|\r/g, '');
      return s;
    }
  }
});
```

Here are other posts on MSDN forums where this issue was mentioned

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e54c217f-28ff-4626-8ce8-a1242081f4d1/ews-11-xml-problem?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SqlServer/en-US/54432b2a-1c5f-4cdc-be33-57fafae2df78/accessing-exchange-2010-sp2-via-ews-20-results-in?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment